# shock-resistant electromechanical linear actuator?

Tags: robotics, actuator, linear-motors

I was wondering, if there is a shock load resistant electromechanical actuator that can withstand powerful impacts?
Is there an electromechanical counterpart for pneumatic cylinders that is as shockresistant as hydraulic or pneumatic actuators?

And if not, is there some kind of way to make them withstand impacts via external parts?

Comment: You need to quantify what you mean by shock, how many G's ??? Actuators based on the solenoid principal can be made very rugged because they are basically simple: a coil and a moving armature . You could take a standard actuator and "beef it up" if you need to.

Comment: I would say about 1000N.
The actuator that I need should be fast (25-50 in/s), powerful (1,500+ lbf), shock-resistant and preferably electromechanical.

Aren't solenoid actuators too weak for this?

Comment: i wonder if the impacts change the properties of ferromagnetic core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDrive Corporation makes a linear actuator called the Eliminator SS rated at 65in/sec and a thrust of 4000lbf. If you want to increase its shock resistance you can take the actuator and mount it in a ruggedized housing of some sort with an opening for actuator arm to do its work. You can call the company and find out if it has a shock rating.

Comment: @testdummy: I see you accepted my answer and that you are a new contributor, it's considered good sportsmanship to upvote an answer if you deem it acceptable ;-)

Comment: Ok, but how is that going to protect the actuator ? I am thinking about it getting its shocks through its arm

Comment: You will have to de-couple the actuator arm from impacts by connecting it to a secondary arm that receives the impacts and is connected to the actuator arm by a coupling like a motor shaft coupling with a rubber spider. Without seeing the actual mechanism the OP is designing , I can only give a general idea on how to solve the problem. If the OP wants me to design something specific, he can always hire me out for a nice fee. :-)

Comment: When do I get my upvote ?